# How to flag/highlight multiple currencies in a Google Spreadsheets column using Apps-Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

For example:

I've a column which is Price and it has the below data
NZ$11.23
NZ$14.23
NZ$15.23
NZ$16.23
Pound£10.23

So I'm trying to write a apps-script code to flag/highlight the cell Pound£10.23. So can someone help achieve this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what you have tried, when happens when you run your code, and what you want to happen instead. Include any error messages. Also, what is the actual data in that cell you want to highlight? Is it a text string `Pound£10.23`? Or perhaps the number `10.23` with currency formatting? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

*Use [conditional formatting rules](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)*

### Explanation

1. Select the range where you want to apply the format (highlight)
2. In format rules select:

   2.1.  Format cells if: `Text contains`

   2.2. Value or formula: you can write the currency that you want to highlight, i.e., `€`, `$` or `£`. You can also select a specific cell, i.e., `=$C$1`
3. If you have picked a cell, you can write there the currency that you want to highlight. In addition, you can use [data validation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) to create a dropdown list of different currencies.

### Example

[image]